# How to sort Set by not unique data?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class EnglishWord implements Comparable<EnglishWord> {

    private String word;// unique
    private int occurenceNumber; //not unique


    public EnglishWord(String word, int occurenceNumber) {
        this.word = word;
        this.occurenceNumber= occurenceNumber;
    }

    public boolean equals(EnglishWord anotherWord) {
        return word.equals(anotherWord.getWord());
    }

    public int compareTo(EnglishWord anotherWord) {
        return occurenceNumber - anotherWord.getOccurenceNumber;
    }
```

I want to add all `EnglishWord`s in to a `Set` where there's exactly one `EnglishWord` object for each unique `word`. I want the `Set` to be sorted by `occurrenceNumber`. The code I have already sorts the words by `occurrenceNumber`, but doesn't add `EnglishWord` with unique `occurrenceNumber` to the `Set`. As code, here is what I mean:

```
Set<EnglishWord> mySet= new TreeSet<EnglishWord>();
mySet.add(new EnglishWord("hello",8));
mySet.add(new EnglishWord("hi",8));
```

After this, `mySet`'s size is 1.

Comment: its not clear.please post an example also.

Comment: I'm afraid it's pretty hard to understand your question. Could you try explaining further, ideally with sample data? (Both input and desired output)?

Comment: @Jon: I rewrote the question to my best understanding, although the *"with unique occurrenceNumber to the Set"* part was/still is confusing to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either define both equals and hashCode or none of them. In your code, for two instances x and y of EnglishWord, it will happen that `x.equals(y) == true` while `x.hashCode() != y.hashCode()`. This is not legal if you expect your class to work with the collection classes from java.util. See [the Object JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). To fix this, add something like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.word.hashCode();
}
```

The equals method must have the signature "public boolean equals(Object other)" -- your equals takes an EnglishWord parameter which results in your method being essentially ignored. Fix:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
    final EnglishWord ow = (EnglishWord) other;
    return ow.word.equals(this.word);
}
```

Generally, using the `@Override` annotation can help a lot to make your coding more robust against this kind of mistake as the runtime error is turned into a compile time error this way.

Additionally, your implementation of the `Comparable` interface should probably make use of generics.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to compare by occurenceNumber, and if that is `0`, then compare by word

```
public int compareTo(EnglishWord anotherWord) {
    int val = occurenceNumber.compareTo(anotherWord.occurenceNumber);
    if (val == 0){ //ok, these have the same occurence, but are they the same word? 
        val = word.compareTo(other.word);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TreeSet` is internally backed by a `TreeMap`.  `TreeMap.put(Object, Ojbect)` will use the `compareTo` method on your `EnglishWord` to determine where the new element should go in the Tree.  If the result of `compareTo` is 0, the method assumes the elements equal.

This is somewhat contradicted by the JavaDoc for `TreeSet.add`

> Adds the specified element to this set
>   if it is not already present. More
>   formally, adds the specified element e
>   to this set if the set contains no
>   element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set
>   already contains the element, the call
>   leaves the set unchanged and returns
>   false.

The JavaDoc for `Comparable` says

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

You need to take this advice and also compare the words when the occurrences are the same.

Answer (score 0):

A collection can have only one index and one ordering.  What you want is two indecies, one which ensure the words are unique and a second which is sorted by occurance number.

To do this you need to maintain two collections, one which a set, keyed by word for uniqueness and the second which is sorted by occurance and word.

Note: fields used in collections this way cannot change or you will get incorrect behaviour.  I suggest you make the fields final.